# Table-Valued parameter IN clause pulling entire table not just values that passed

Tags: c#, sql

I have created Table-Valued parameter to use in `IN` clause. Looks like everything is perfect for I am getting entire table ids rather what I passed in `IN` clause. I passed 6 ids but return I got
120K ids.

Let know where I am making wrong.

```
CREATE TYPE StringsList as Table (Id varchar(100));
```

### C#

```
    MemberNumbers = "3229622,4183229,3257553,3003673,3358312,0682773";
    string[] memberIds = MemberNumbers.Split(',');

 public void GetMemberInfoAndMemberSubscriptionsUsingSP(string[] ids, ref string errMsg)
        {
            
            var result = new List<subscriptionExt>();
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["personifyConn"];
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetMemberInfoAndMemberSubscriptions", conn))
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));

                    foreach (var id in ids)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(id);
                    }

                    var parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ListIds", dt);
                    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
               }
           }
       }
```

### SQL

```
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMemberInfoAndMemberSubscriptions] ( @ListIds StringsList READONLY)
AS

BEGIN
  

   SELECT [MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID], USR_SPE_Membership_Status 
     FROM CUSTOMER WHERE [MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID] 
   IN  (SELECT [MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID] FROM @ListIds)

END
```

I don't anything wrong here.

Comment: There's a very good reason to use alias prefixes (to identify the intended source table) to specify columns in subqueries. You've just experienced why. Had you said `(SELECT l.[MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID] FROM @ListIds l)` you'd have been given a nice error message rather than a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

@ListIds do not have the column MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID. In Subquery it should be Id instead of MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID.

```
SELECT [MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID], USR_SPE_Membership_Status 
     FROM CUSTOMER WHERE [MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID] 
   IN  (SELECT ID FROM @ListIds)
```